# How do I write this tricky SQL query?

Tags: sql

**[FYI, this is not homework — I guess everyone thinks that because I made an effort to format my question in a simple readable form?  Again, not homework.  I'm at work, and just trying to learn.  Thanks.]**

I'm very stuck on a tricky one.  I'm a Java guy, I'm not a SQL guy, so any help with this is GREATLY appreciated!

I have a PROJECT table and a TASK table like so:

```
**PROJECT**
projectId
name
```

PROJECT has many TASKs:

```
**TASK**
taskId
projectId
description
userId // the user who is assigned the task
status // either "IN_PROGRESS" or "COMPLETE"
sequence // the numeric sequence of the TASK in the PROJECT
```

For example:

```
Project
   projectId=100
   name="Build House"
Task
   taskId=250 // task IDs are not necessary in numerical order
   sequence=1
   description="Pour Foundation"
   userId=55
   status="COMPLETE"
Task
   taskId=240
   sequence=2
   description="Build walls"
   userId=56
   status="COMPLETE"
Task
   taskId=260
   sequence=3
   description="Install windows"
   userId=57
   status="IN_PROGRESS"
Task
   taskId=245
   sequence=4
   description="Build roof"
   userId=58
   status="IN_PROGRESS"
```

I need two queries:

(1) For a given projectId, get the 'current task'.  The current task is the task number with the smallest `sequence` number which is not complete.  In my example, `getCurrentTask(projectId=100)` would return taskId 260 (because it's the first one that is incomplete).

(2) For a given userId, get the list of projects where he is assigned to a 'current task'.  In my example, `getProjectsForUserId(userId=57)` would return projectId 100; `getProjectsForUserId(userId=58)` would return nothing.

Comment: Nothing tricky about this, just learn about inner joins and aggregate functions.

Comment: Your example seems incorrect to me: i dont understand why getProjectsForUserId(58) should return nothing. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @DocJones - getProjectsForUserId(58) returns nothing because userId 58 is not assigned to a 'current task'.  Task "install windows" is the current task.  The way the system works is, user 58 that he can start his "build roof" rask after "Install windows" is complete.  Thanks.

Comment: @DocJones - it occurs to me that "IN_PROGRESS" is not the best name for the status, since "Build roof" cannot be in progress until "Install Windows" is completed. I will suggest to my team that we change "IN_PROGRESS" to "INCOMPLETE" or maybe "PENDING", thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT min(taskID) FROM Task WHERE ProjectID = ? and status <> "COMPLETE";

SELECT projectID FROM 
Tasks T INNER JOIN
(SELECT min(taskID) as taskID, projectID FROM Task GROUP BY projectID WHERE status <> "COMPLETE")
AS CT on CT.taskID = T.taskID
WHERE T.userId = ?'
```

**EDIT**

The queries below order by sequence, instead of TaskID.

```
SELECT taskID from Task T INNER JOIN
(SELECT min(sequence) as sequence, projectID FROM Task GROUP BY projectID WHERE status <> "COMPLETE")
   AS CT on CT.sequence = T.sequence AND CT.projectID = T.projectID
WHERE T.projectID = ?;

SELECT projectID FROM 
Task T INNER JOIN
(SELECT min(sequence) as sequence, projectID FROM Task GROUP BY projectID WHERE status <> "COMPLETE")
   AS CT on CT.sequence = T.sequence AND CT.projectID = T.projectID
WHERE T.userID = ?;
```

Comment: I can't count on the taskID's being in numerical order (because they are all created and then reordered before the project starts).  That's why there's a sequence number.  How would you tweak the query to factor in the sequence number?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TASK
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROJECT ON 
    TASK.PROJECTID=PROJECT.PROJECTID 
WHERE TASK.STATUS='IN_PROGRESS' 
  AND PROJECT.PROJECTID=?
ORDER BY SEQUENCE ASC
```

Comment: Its a questions - why do you flag my (not yet finished) answer?

Comment: Grrr ... IT'S NOT HOMEWORK! What's wrong with stackoverflow today? I'm trying to get work done here.

Comment: hehe - Apparently, my (1) should work well. However, @therealmitchconnors answer looks very well formed.

Comment: @DocJones, turns out therealmitchconnors answer is incorrect; I added a comment there explaining why

Answer (score 0):

First Query (updated):

```
SELECT taskId FROM `task` 
WHERE `projectId`=100 AND `status` = "IN_PROGRESS" 
ORDER BY `sequence`
LIMIT 1
```

Second one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(projectId) FROM task 
WHERE userId=57 AND `status` = "IN_PROGRESS"
ORDER BY `sequence`
```

P.S. Didn't added any joins to project table, because in your task you asked only about ids.

Comment: It can't be that simple.  I think you're missing the bit about the sequence number?  I only want the first task in numerical order that is 'IN_PROGRESS', not all tasks for the user that are 'IN_PROGRESS'.

Comment: Hmm. If you will add "LIMIT 1" to the end of the query it should work. Understood second task now. One moment :)

Comment: You would need an ORDER BY as well (given the assumption he is searching for the next task to be done)

Comment: @DocJones Just FYI, got your #1 working, except I had to change `LIMIT 1` (MySQL) to `WHERE rownum <= 1` (Oracle).  Will try your #2 first thing tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: @DocJones Problem with your #2, I think.  It will return the projectId if the user is assigned to any "IN_PROGRESS" task in the project.  I only want the projectId if the user is assigned to the 'current' task "IN_PROGRESS" task in the project.

Comment: You are not referring to my answer but to @true :)

Answer (score 0):

If it were homework, I'd give these hints:

(1): A simple query over `Tasks` will do. (You know the project ID after all, right?) Use aggregate functions and a `WHERE` clause.

(2): Try quering `Projects` using a `WHERE EXISTS ...` construct. `DISTINCT` might come in handy, too.

**EDIT:** You don't even need to touch `Projects` for the second query, too. The queries posted by @true look correct.

**EDIT^2:** ...but @true's query don't consider the subtlety that only the "current" tasks are of interest.

Comment: <rolls eyes> Thanks for the help, but it's not homework. I'm a professional java programmer with very basic SQL knowledge. I hope one day you get stuck on a complicated Java problem so I can belittle your problem with a 'hint'. ;)

Comment: I didn't add the homework tag.  I don't know where it came from.

Comment: Somebody added it, usually we're not expected to do this without the authors consent. Care to remove it and explicitly explain this in your question?